# Maya Python Using "cmds.file" to export

Tags: python, export, maya

I am still a newbie when it comes to python in general so bear with me.

I am trying to make a little export script for maya and cant seem to set the options flag for the "file" command.

I want to specify the options for the "file" command with radio buttons.

I have a radio control like this:

```
Material = ""

MaterialRadio = cmds.radioButton("Material")

def MaterialFunc ():
   MaterialCheck = cmds.radioButton(MaterialRadio, q=True, sl=True)
   return MaterialCheck

if MaterialCheck == True:
    Material = "1"   
                
if MaterialCheck == False:
    Material  = "0"
```

The options Flag for the file command takes only strings, so something like this doenst seem to work:

To test, i force Material = "0"

```
Material = "0"
cmds.file (exportPath, type=OBJexport, op=Material )
```

Using strings, `op="material=0")` also doenst seem to work though.

Also keep in mind, i want to set multiple flags with radio controls.
So it should look something like this in the end:

```
cmds.file (exportPath, type=OBJexport, op=[material, groups, ptgroups, smoothing, normals] )
```

Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: If possible please provide a complete executable script. Your provided script simply makes no sense because you use the local variable `MaterialCheck` and return it, but the function `MaterialFunc` is called nowhere and the return value is not used anywhere. So the `MaterialCheck`in the if-expressions is always undefined.

Comment: i edited my initial post.

Comment: I'ts more clear now. If I understand correctly, then your file example works this way: `cmds.file (exportPath, type=OBJexport, op=[material, groups, ptgroups, smoothing, normals] )`? If so, did you try to make a list as argument exactly as in your example? something like `cmds.file (exportPath, type=OBJexport, op=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0])` if op is always a fixed value?

Comment: sry for the late replay. op=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]) doenst work as `op` is expecting strings. your example only gives me the error: `Invalid arguments for flag 'op'.  Expected string, got [ int, int, int, int, int ]` which is why in my executable script it says: `op="groups=0; ptgroups=0; materials=0; smoothing=1; normals=0"`
Eventually i want to be able to change for exmple `materials=1` to `materials=0` etc. with radio buttons in the UI.
This doenst work tho, as changing 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 wont make a difference. The Material will get exported no matter what.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt read your code carefully. So if you test it in the script editor with a simple line like this: `cmds.file("somepath/tst.obj", force=True, op="groups=0;ptgroups=0;materials=0;smoothing=0;normals=0", typ="OBJexport", pr=True, es=True)` and you change materials from 0 to 1, there is no difference? It works fine here.

Comment: If i export like this: `op="groups=0;ptgroups=0;materials=0;smoothing=0;normals=0` it makes no difference if material is set to 0 or 1. 
If i do it like in you new answer, it works tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options can be easily set by following this pattern:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
doMaterial = 0
doNormals = 1
options = "groups=0;ptgroups=0;materials={0};smoothing=1;normals={1}".format(doMaterial, doNormals)
cmds.file("somepath/tst.obj", force=True, op=options, typ="OBJexport", pr=True, es=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work.